# Installing Strange Eons software

Tags: software-installation

I would like to install a new version of Strange Eons application for Ubuntu.
link: https://strangeeons.cgjennings.ca/download.html
I am a beginner with Ubuntu. I was able to resolve this issue with the previous version, but now it seems that the procedure has changed.

Comment: Please include the error messages you experience when following the official instructions.

Comment: ~/Downloads$ dpkg -i strange-eons-linux-amd64-b4241.deb
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege

Comment: You need to run the command with sudo: `sudo dpkg -i strange-eons-linux-amd64-b4241.deb `

Comment: Thak you. It worked!